# How to insert from QUEUE to 2D LIST

Tags: c++, list, stl, queue

I have a pretty basic question. How to push from QUEUE to LIST. I am pretty much copying from queue to list. Here is my example:

```
list<list<BoardingTicket>> boardPassenger(queue<BoardingTicket>& waitingLine){
     list< list<BoardingTicket>> combinedList;
     while(!waitingLine.empty()){
          combinedList.push_back(waitingLine.front()); 
          waitingLine.pop();
     }

     return combinedList;
}
```

Is it any easier way or do I need to do it with iterators.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: LINE 4 (combinedList.push_back(waitingLine.front());) DOESN'T WORK!**

Comment: You can't iterate over a queue, so that's not an option..

Comment: Why are you using a list of lists? Don't you simply want `list<BoardingTicket>`?

Comment: @Blastfurnace it's like that because of the rest of the assigment. And I can only change the internals of the function. Because after i hopefully finish this will go through automated test.

Comment: A `list<list<foo>>` is a two-dimensional data structure. You need to decide where the queue elements will go. Do you want each one in its own list? One long list inside another single list? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want to use iterators on `std::queue<T>`, it isn't possible. There are no iterators for them.

If u want to use the iterator of the list but I think `push_back()` is easier and more clear.

Use the following

```
list<list<BoardingTicket>> boardPassenger(queue<BoardingTicket>& waitingLine){
     list<BoardingTicket> combinedList;
     while(!waitingLine.empty()){
          combinedList.insert(combinedList.begin(), waitingLine.front());
          waitingLine.pop();
     }

     return list<list<BoardingTicket>>{std::move(combinedList)};//#include<utility>
}
```

Comment: `std::queue` does not have any iterators.

Comment: Now error says: insert: cannot convert argument 2 from '_Ty' to '_Ty &&'

Comment: I think something is wrong with insert. It basically says that i don't have enough arguments for insert

Comment: @asmmo still problem with .insert()

Comment: Error (active) E0304 no instance of overloaded function "std::list<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=std::list<BoardingTicket, std::allocator<BoardingTicket>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::list<BoardingTicket, std::allocator<BoardingTicket>>>]" matches the argument list

Comment: Oh I see. SORRY! I didn't use "list<BoardingTicket> combinedList;" I used list "<list<>>" 
I just didn't see it! Thanks a lot!